# Annotate csv column in scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have two dataset in csv format:

df2

```
type  prediction          100000     155000    
 0           0            2.60994   3.40305
 1           1           10.82100  34.68900
 0           0            4.29470   3.74023
 0           0            7.81339   9.92839
 0           0           28.37480  33.58000
```

df

```
 TIMESTEP   id  type         y         z         v_acc
  100000   8054     1     -0.317192 -0.315662   15.54430
  100000    669     0      0.352031 -0.008087   2.60994 
  100000    520     0      0.437786  0.000325   5.28670
  100000   2303     1      0.263105  0.132615   7.81339 
  105000   8055     1      0.113863  0.036407   5.94311
```

I am trying to match value of `df2[100000]` to `df1[v_acc]`. If value matched, I am making scatter plot from `df` with columns `y` and `z`. After that I want to to annoted scatter point with matched value.

What I want is:

[image]

(I want all annotaions in a same plot).

I tried to code in python for such condition but I am not getting all annotation points in a single plot instead I am getting multi plots with a single annotation.
I am also getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py:339, in BaseFormatter.__call__(self, obj)
    337     pass
    338 else:
--> 339     return printer(obj)
    340 # Finally look for special method names
    341 method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py:151, in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
    148     from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
    149     FigureCanvasBase(fig)
--> 151 fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    152 data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    153 if fmt == 'svg':

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:2295, in FigureCanvasBase.print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2289     renderer = _get_renderer(
   2290         self.figure,
   2291         functools.partial(
   2292             print_method, orientation=orientation)
   2293     )
   2294     with getattr(renderer, "_draw_disabled", nullcontext)():
-> 2295         self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2297 if bbox_inches:
...
    189 if len(self) == 1:
    190     return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 191 raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

Can I get some help to make a plot as I want?

Thank you.
My code is here:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('./result.csv')
print(df2.columns)
#print(df2.head(10))
df  = pd.read_csv('./main.csv')
df = df[df['TIMESTEP'] == 100000]

for i in df['v_acc']:
    for j in df2['100000']:
        # sometimes numbers are long and different after decimals.So mathing 0.2f only
        if "{0:0.2f}".format(i) == "{0:0.2f}".format(j):
            plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
            sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = "y", y = "z", hue = "type", palette=['red','dodgerblue'], legend='full')
            plt.annotate(i, (df['y'][df['v_acc'] == i], df['z'][df['v_acc'] == i]))
            plt.grid(False)
            plt.show()
            break
```

Comment: The question was related to `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`, which isn't answered by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason for the multiple plots is because are you using `plt.figure()` inside the loop. This will create a single figure for each loop. You need to create that outside and only the individual scatter and annotate within the loop. Here is the updated code that ran for the data you provided. Other than that, think your code is fine...

```
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize = (7,7)) ### Keep this before the loop and call it as subplot
for i in df['v_acc']:
    for j in df2[100000]:
        # sometimes numbers are long and different after decimals.So mathing 0.2f only
        if "{0:0.2f}".format(i) == "{0:0.2f}".format(j):
            #plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
            ax=sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = "y", y = "z", hue = "type", palette=['red','dodgerblue'], legend='full')
            ax.annotate(i, (df['y'][df['v_acc'] == i], df['z'][df['v_acc'] == i]))
            break

plt.grid(False)  ### Keep these two after the loop, just one show for one plot
plt.show()
```

**Output plot**

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for pointing out my mistake. I am still getting this error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>.  Any idea to get rid of this error?

Comment: which line of code are you getting the error? In the question, there is a mention of it, but doesn't have full trace. Can you add the full trace there? Also, pls run `df.info()` and add the output there

Comment: error is from this line. My data includes all float type.

Comment: I dont see 'this line'....  where have you added it? In the question you only have 2 lines, but they are not your code. The data I have used is as provided - df and df2 at the start of the question

Comment: Sorry, my bad, this line: 'ax.annotate(i, (df['y'][df['v_acc'] == i], df['z'][df['v_acc'] == i]))'

Comment: I change all columns in DF to float. It still does not give me any error. Are you sure the error is in `plt.annotate()` line? Please paste the full error traceback

Comment: I updated my question with full error. Thanks. Really appreciate you time.

Comment: @Codeholic - Bit of a shooting in the dark as I am not seeing the error. Based on your feedback, can you pls replace the annotate line with this and try? `ax.annotate(i, (df['y'][df['v_acc'] == i].to_list()[0], df['z'][df['v_acc'] == i].to_list()[0]))`. As you mentioned, if the coordinates are not reading, I am forcing them to a float. let me know....